# Generate Source Code for specific file using Doxygen

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard, doxygen-wizard, doxygen-addtogroup

Setting SOURCE_BROWSER = TRUE show source code for all files.

**Is it possible to show source of specific file?**
Or enable \ref or equivalent using SOURCE_BROWSER = FALSE
Or remove source code for specifics files if SOURCE_BROWSER = TRUE
Or equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using [\include](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinclude) and [\verbinclude](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdverbinclude).

```
/**
* \verbinclude Example.cs
* \include Example.cs
* */
public class Example
{

}
```